# How to fade in a div message on page load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a div message when the page loads using fadein and fadeout after 3 secs but my code does not seem to work, any help please? what am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="message" class="jumbotron" style="display:none;">
    <p><?php echo $m; ?></p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('div#message').fadeIn(3000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);

});
```

Comment: Your code is correct. The issue must be another one.

Comment: Have you included jQueryUI lib? Mayby you re missing it, code seems to be ok.

Comment: @Beri How does jQueryUI have to do anything with this?

Comment: Temporarily try changing style to `display:block` and check that the variable is being echoed.

Comment: Doesn't animation functionality lies inside UI lib?

Comment: @Beri no, it is [part of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: Any errors on the javascript console? Also can you show us the html output instead of the PHP?

Comment: what's the problem its working http://jsfiddle.net/3mhcq0uc/

Comment: @Beri fadein and fadeout are part of Jquery. Jquery UI is dependent on Jquery to work, so it will always be used with Jquery. That's why you probably got it mixed up. Anyway good idea to check that Jquery is being included in the page.

Comment: Did you include main jquery library in your code??

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me ([Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9v2estx6/)). The issue is either that you haven't included a valid link to the jQuery library, or there is an error that occurs before it gets to the below code that causes it to stop executing.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div#message').fadeIn(3000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fade in the message on page load and then set a timeout in order to fade out after 3 seconds

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/ha35gd58/2/)

**EDIT**

```
$('#message').fadeIn()
.queue(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#message').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Comment: Why is `setTimeout` there? How would this do what OP wants?

Comment: Made an edit: now it fades in on page load, and fades out after 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing this script on the same page as the div element or does this lies in an external page?
If on external page then try checking if the control even passes to this page or not by simply putting an alert box or not.
If this script is on the same page, then make sure you write this script after the element you defined as if you have written this on the top or before the #message div then the script would run before it even gets loaded on page and you would not see any difference.

Comment: Your Script is correct whatsoever. If it doesnt works means the control is not getting passed to this handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#message').fadeIn(3000,function()
{
    $(this).delay(3000);
    $(this).fadeOut(200);

});
```

Hope this will work for you.